# how to set colon between key value in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui

How can i set colon in array . I have just concatenate with colon . please help me with other solution .

```js
var data = [{"name":"a","id":"1"},{"name":"b","id":"2"}];
var obj = [];
$.each(data,function(k,v){
  obj.push(v.id + ":"+ v.name); 
});
  console.log(" obj is "+ JSON.stringify(obj));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Value should be **["1:a", "2:b"]**

Comment: You snippet returns `["1:a","2:b"]` and you say `Value should be ["1:a","2:b"]`. What is the problem?

Comment: Its pushed as string value and not json object.

Comment: yes because i have just concatenate with the colon  .. is there any other way to get the same ? @ Carsten Løvbo Andersen

Comment: @Harshitha it's really not clear what you're asking as your example already does what you need...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the object and then push it into array:

```
$.each(data,function(k,v){
 var jo = {};
 jo[v.id] = v.name;
 obj.push(jo); 
});
```